# what will be the behaviour of Kafka...?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am stuck in a typical use case or scenario where I am not sure what will be the behavior of Kafka..

> SCENERIO : I am using Spring Kafka with spring Boot. In my application I am having one Rest end point which will read all messages from the beginning of a topic to check for the duplication of message then write to topic if not duplicate.

I am confused about what will be the behavior of the application when multiple instances of same microservice are deployed and offset is moved for seekFromBegining operation.

few questions in my mind are :

```
do reading from beginning of a topic (with the help of seek) block the topic ?
If Yes. then how to solve this typical use case where we have to validate for the 
duplication of message before writing to the topic.
```

Using DB is not a solution because it will be resource intensive. and make the application slower.

Thanks everyone in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [Log Compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) feature:

> Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain at least the last known value for each message key within the log of data for a single topic partition.

Therefore when you specify some unique `message key`, you won't have more than one of them in the partition. And with that you don't need to read topic before storing at all.

Comment: Yes we are using Keys while writing to the Kafka Topics. does this mean that Topic will not be blocked by one instance while reading.

Comment: Well, that's not related somehow to the story. I suggested you absolutely different solution which comes as an out-of-the-box solution in Kafka. I just don't see reason to read anything from that REST service, if you can fix your duplication concern via log compaction.

Comment: Thanks !!! I will definitely look into log compaction feature. this can also help us to remove duplicate. but check is needed so that rest-endpoint consuming application be notified for duplicate message.

Comment: There is no blocking on the topic. You just create a `KafkaConsumer` with a unique consumer group each time and use `auto.offset.reset` as `earliest`. So, this new group will always read topic from the beginning and will never collide with other groups on the same topic. But log compaction functionality still will be there. This is already a producer feature, not consumer.